# Hide all elements with duplicate class names besides the first with CSS

Tags: css

I have a loop displaying some markup that has dynamic class names. Is it possible to hide all elements with duplicate class name besides the first instance? For example below I would only want the first `.SomethingDynamic1` and the first `.SomethingDynamic2` to be visible.

I think I might be able to use the `div[class^="group"]` "starts with" attribute selector to achieve this but am I able to match dynamic text after that and filter out the duplicates? I would prefer a CSS only solution if possible.

```
<div class="group-SomethingDynamic1">
<div class="group-SomethingDynamic1">
<div class="group-SomethingDynamic1">
<div class="group-SomethingDynamic1">
<div class="group-SomethingDynamic2">
<div class="group-SomethingDynamic2">
<div class="group-SomethingDynamic2">
<div class="group-SomethingDynamic2">
```

Comment: You'll need to know the dynamic part beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update (credit @Temani Afif)

If you want a CSS only solution, you will need to know the classes to filter beforehand.

Given that, you can simply use a siblings selector like the following:

```
.group-SomethingDynamic1 ~ .group-SomethingDynamic1 {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ab8kpk)

Comment: Thanks, I assumed as such but was holding out hope for some way to match elements with duplicate classes

Comment: @noclist this doesn't work at all even if you know the classes: https://jsfiddle.net/7mte9wfa/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are correct indeed, as I am not selecting the siblings, I have updated the answer with the correct solution

Comment: I have now added an example of this working with the OP code

Comment: the `:not(:first-of-type)` is useless

Comment: Again, you are indeed correct, thanks for the feedback I did not know it is not necessary. Everyday is a school day :)